# Rails update user without current password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I read the following page and other q's on SO(which mostly lead here or change it a little)

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Ok, i understand i can just override 'update_with_password', and i am able to change it, problem is after it it logs the user out and the described

```
sign_in @user, :bypass => true
redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
```

technique won't work!
if i dont sign in it just redirects me to 403, if i do, it says

```
undefined method `after_update_path_for' for #<AdminsController:0x00000005ab20e8>
```

moreover, if i redirect to say, static url, it says i have a double redirect

Comment: I think you need to override password_required? on the model.

Comment: why you are overriding `update_with_password`?  you can directly update the password with update_attributes method passing password and password_confirmation.